# Open Office doc imported from Word stuck on read only

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer, microsoft-word

I am trying to edit a document I was mailed as a Word document (.doc), but Writer will not let me edit it as it is read only.  The security setting "Open this document as read only" checkbox is clear.  How can I make this document editable without copy and pasting everything into a new document?

Comment: right click on the document, select properties, uncheck read only. problem should be solved

Comment: Does opening it (in read only), resaving it with a new name, then opening the newly saved version help?

Comment: Read only isn't set on the actual file.

Comment: ''but Writer will not let me edit it as it is read only. ''

Comment: yes, it is read only to Writer, not to the OS user.

Comment: have you given writer administrator privilages?